# Form is submitted when I click on the button in form. How to avoid this?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter-boostrap and I'd like to use [these radio-buttons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) in my form.
The problem is when I click on any of these buttons, the form is immediately submitted.
How to avoid this? I just want to use default buttons like radio-buttons.

from:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :type, :class => 'control-label' %>

      <div class="controls">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
          <button class="btn">Button_1</button>
          <button class="btn">Button_2</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', products_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

javascript:

```
// application.js
$('.tabs').button();
```

Comment: A little late, but what helped me was [Event Object's preventDefault() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp). something like `$('.btn').onClick(function(evt){evt.preventDefault();});`

Answer (score 183, accepted):

From the fine [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-button-element):

> A *button* element with no *type* attribute specified represents the same thing as a button element with its type attribute set to *"submit"*.

And a [`<button type="submit">`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-button-type-submit-button) submits the form rather than behaving like a simple [`<button type="button">` push-button](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-button-type-button).

The [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) says the same thing:

> **type = submit|button|reset** [CI]
>   This attribute declares the type of the button. Possible values:
>
> - `submit`: Creates a submit button. This is the default value.
> - `reset`: Creates a reset button.
> - `button`: Creates a push button.

So your `<button>` elements:

```
<button class="btn">Button_1</button>
<button class="btn">Button_2</button>
```

are the same as these (in compliant browsers):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn">Button_1</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Button_2</button>
```

and any time you hit one of those buttons you'll submit your form.

The solution is to use plain buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Button_1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button_2</button>
```

Some versions of IE default to `type="button"` despite what the standard says. You should always specify the `type` attribute when using a `<button>` just to be sure that you will get the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: Nice, I was having so much trouble stopping every button in my ROR forms from submitting to the create action. Thanks so much for clearing this up.

Comment: @Abdul The time wasn't wasted if it taught you to always include the `type` attribute on your `<button>`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preventDefault()` for this

```
$('.btn').onClick(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

> or you can update your html with following code (just add `type="button"`) in button tag

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :type, :class => 'control-label' %>

      <div class="controls">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
          <button class="btn" type="button">Button_1</button>
          <button class="btn" type="button">Button_2</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', products_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly using rails form helper also by specifying `type` as an option to "button":

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :type, :class => 'control-label' %>

      <div class="controls">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
          <%= f.button "Button_1", type: "button", class: "btn" %>
          <%= f.button "Button_2", type: "button", class: "btn" %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', products_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```