# bootstrap html click button without submit form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code

```
        <form class="form-horizontal">

          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <button onclick="javascript:add_user_group(2);" class="btn">add</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        <table id="users-table" class="table table-striped" >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>User Name</th>
              <th>Delete</th>            
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>

      </form>
```

I just want to add a new row to a table when a add button clicked, but it seems a click of the add button triggers a submission of  form.

Isn't is only a button with

```
 type=submit
```

to submit form. Or any button in a form triggers a submission of form ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with bootstrap but what happens if you make the `add_user_group()` function `return false;` after adding the row?

Comment: @AnthonyClark waw. it works (not triggers a form submission)!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Having `false` returned in the function called `onclick` will prevent form submission. :)

```
onclick="javascript:add_user_group(2);return false;"
```

Comment: Use Button Tag's Type to button        Like       <button type=''button" onclick="Javascript:myFunction()">ANOTHER TASK</button>

Answer (score 53):

No need to use Javascript. Just set `type="button"` to overwrite the implicit `type="submit"`. 
This can also be found in the HTML5 specs as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9643866/2175370

Comment: This should be the real solution. The other answer does not avoid the form submit by pressing enter in a form field.

Comment: This solution only gives you a input to style, and gives you limited styling options.