# Please help me prevent Bootstrap radio buttons from submitting my form too early (using Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, mailchimp

**My process:**

1. First I designed a signup form for my website using Bootstrap
2. Then, I created a signup form using MailChimp, so I can track and contact my signups
3. I then generated the embed form HTML markup, and combined the two

**The issue:**

The part that is breaking the form is that the Bootstrap radio button toggle uses input type="button" and the MailChimp form I am trying to map it to uses type="radio".

If I don't use type="radio", the submission works but when I check the information on my subscribers in MailChimp, I am missing data from that part of the form on.

If I use type="radio", the form prematurely submits when the user tries to use the toggle button, so basically the form submits before they can finish filling out the rest of the form.

*JSFiddle Demo of the issue is here:* http://jsfiddle.net/halsey/qwPzy/9/

**The solution?**

I am aware of threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643806/form-is-submitted-when-i-click-on-the-button-in-form-how-to-avoid-this), which say you will need to override this behavior with javascript, but I can't find an example of how to do this.

I'm sure this is embarrassingly easy but I am having trouble locating resources to help me learn how to fix this. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

**Footnote**

StackOverflow is preventing me from linking to JSFiddle without embedding code. I would encourage you to use the link above, but my broken attempt at embedding the code is below. Apologies for the weird formatting but I am having trouble embedding the code in one chunk - I am a StackOverflow beginner.

HTML:

```
<form action="http://foorder.us6.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=81c3da3b3ebbf564cf50a78ff&amp;id=f16451f556" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

                            <fieldset class="mc-field-group">


                                <div class="form-field input-prepend">

                                        <span class="add-on">http://Foorder.com/</span>

                                        <input class="span3 required" id="prependedInput mce-MMERGE2" type="text" placeholder="YourProfile" value="" name="MMERGE2">

                                 </div><!-- / .formfield .input-prepend -->


                                <div class="form-field">


                                       <input type="email" class="span3 required email" placeholder="Email" value="" name="EMAIL" id="mce-EMAIL">



                                    <input type="text" class="span2 required" placeholder="Zip Code" value="" name="MMERGE8" id="mce-MMERGE8">

                                </div><!-- / .formfield -->

                                <div class="form-field">



                                      I want to&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                                             <button type="radio" class="btn" value="Buy" name="MMERGE3" id="mce-MMERGE3-0">Buy</button>
                                             <button type="radio" class="btn" value="Sell" name="MMERGE3" id="mce-MMERGE3-1">Sell</button>
                                        </div>
                                      &nbsp;&nbsp;items on Foorder

                                </div><!-- / .formfield -->

                                <div class="form-field">

                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#promo-code-toggle">

                                            Have a promo code?

                                         </button>


                                        <div id="promo-code-toggle" class="collapse">

                                                   <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Promo Code" value="" name="MMERGE1 promocodeinput" id="mce-MMERGE1 promo-code-input">


                                        </div><!-- / .formfield -->




                                </div><!-- / .formfield -->


                                 <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">

                                        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>

                                        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>

                                </div>  


                                <div class="form-field">


                                    <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-primary" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe">Submit</button>

                                </div><!-- / .formfield -->


                            </fieldset>

                       </form>
```

CSS HEAD links:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Javascript BODY links:

```
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/bootstrap-affix.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/holder/holder.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/application.js"></script>
<script src="http://foorder.com/_Resources/SBX/js/custom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting an "onsubmit" on the form and running thru a function to determine testing?

ala

```
<form action="http://foorder.us6.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=81c3da3b3ebbf564cf50a78ff&amp;
    id=f16451f556" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
    name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" 
    onsubmit="return checkValidity(this);">
```

and in your js code:

```
function checkValidity(form){
  if(){
       // return false <-- doesn't submit
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to upvote but apparently I don't have enough of a reputation around here :)

Comment: oh no worries. If you use this solution, don't hesitate to 'accept' the answer. Click the check image. But no worries, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

So this JSFiddle that I found on the Bootstrap Github worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/charettes/SauLj/

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio_1" />
<label class="btn" for="radio_1">Radio one</label>
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio_2" />
<label class="btn" for="radio_2">Radio two</label>
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio_3" />
<label class="btn" for="radio_3">Disabled radio three</label>
```

CSS:

```
    .btn-group > input {
    display: none;
}

.btn-group input:first-child + .btn {
     /* This is an actual copy/paste of the .btn-group .btn:first-child style */
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

input:checked + label.btn {
    /* This is an actual copy/paste of the .btn:active style */
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    outline: 0 none;
}

input[disabled] + label.btn {
    /* This is an actual copy/paste of the .btn:disabled style */
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.65;
}
```