# Button's function always called when enter key is pressed at text input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

This code represents a html markup where the user can add one or more phones to her/his profile. So, I use backbone to add text fields where the user can specify them.

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="..">

   <!-- Here I have another text input controls -->

    <!-- START: backbone view -->
    <div id="phones">
        <div class="phones-container">
            <!-- New phone template [label, text input] -->      
        </div>

        <!-- Add phone template button -->
        <button id="btn-add-phone">Add another phone</button>
    </div>
    <!-- END: backbone view -->
</form>
```

The phone template looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group tpl-phone">
    <label class="">Other:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-7 controls">
        <input value="" type="tel" class="reference" name="reference[]" >
    </div>
</div>
```

In backbone I have a function that add a new phone template to the view.

> **Notice that...** the backbone view is just a portion of the form.

```
var PhoneEditorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#phones',
    events: {
        "click #btn-add-phone": "onAddPhoneTemplate",
        "keyup .reference": "onTypingReference"
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'onAddPhoneTemplate', 'onTypingReference', 'render');
        this.model = new PhoneEditor(options);
        this.render();
    },

    onAddPhoneTemplate: function(event){
        event && event.preventDefault(); //prevents submit form 
        console.log('onAddPhoneTemplate()');
        var $template = $('.tpl-phone').clone().removeClass('tpl-phone');

        $('.phones-container').append($template);
    }, 

    onTypingReference: function(event){
        event && event.preventDefault(); 
        if(event.which == 13){
            console.log('enter key');
        }
    },

    render: function(){
    }
});
```

**What is the problem?** If the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key at any text field whaterver if it is inside or outside of view's scope, for some reason `onAddPhoneTemplate()` function is called again and another phone's template is added to the view.

- The expected behavior on enter key is do nothing, console's output:

  ```
  enter key
  ```
- However, after pressing enter key I get at console:

  ```
  onAddPhoneTemplate()
  enter key
  ```

Comment: This is [implicit submission](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#implicit-submission) in action.

Comment: Same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9643806/479863) but different environment so not quite a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your button to `type=button`.

By default a button is `type=submit` unless otherwise specified so when placed in a form it will trigger the form to submit.

When a `type=submit` exists in form, hitting `enter` will also trigger the form submit

```
<button type="button" id="btn-add-phone">Add another phone</button>
```

Comment: I never thought that the problem resided there. I scanned my backbone code for at least 1 one hour. Thank so much, have a good day

Comment: no problem... I know this rule and still slap myself sometimes for messing up with it